# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError with XML

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb, jax-ws

I have the following XML

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlType(propOrder = { "name", "transforms", "qualitycontrols"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Process {

@XmlElement
private String name;      

@XmlElement(name = "transform")
private List<Transform> transforms = new ArrayList<Transform>();

@XmlElement(name = "qualitycontrol")
private List<QualityControl> qualitycontrols = new ArrayList<QualityControl>();

public Process() {
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}  

public void add(Transform transform) {
    transforms.add(transform);
}

public List<Transform> getTransforms() {
    return transforms;
}

public List<QualityControl> getQualitycontrols() {
    return qualitycontrols;
}

public void add(QualityControl qualitycontrol) {
    qualitycontrols.add(qualitycontrol);
}
}
```

The transform node works just fine and I added the qualitycontrol node which is not working.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="qualitycontrol")
@XmlType(propOrder = { "template"})
public class QualityControl {

private String template;

public QualityControl() {
}

public String getTemplate() {
    return template;
}

public void setTemplate(String template) {
    this.template = template;
}

}
```

When I use public static main to test this code everything works fine but when it gets deployed to the server I get this message:
  ERROR [ProcessMDB] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: model.Process.getQualitycontrols()Ljava/util/List;

What am I missing ?? 
All help is highly appreciated.

Thanks
Joey.

Comment: Is the same jar of the library (same version) deployed on the server as on your local machine?

Comment: I checked the class file generated. It does have that the .getQualitycontrols() method.

Comment: Gets this class bundled in the war file also?

Comment: It is in the lib folder. In a jar. It is not supposed to be in a war file.

Comment: And the jar in the lib folder was replaced by the new one? What if you remove the jar from the lib folder, do you get the same error? Maybe the JVM loads the class from another jar which it sees on the classpath...

Comment: Yes it was replaced by the new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to  user714965 !! I deleted the jar and I was still getting the same error. So I looked for the jar and found that it was in the lib of another ear. After deleting that ear, things started breaking. After rebuilding the ear, the method was found !! No more java.lang.NoSuchMethodError. Thanks again !! Spent a lot of time on this one.